# Using styled-jsx, How can I test style with enzyme?

Tags: jestjs, enzyme, next.js, styled-jsx

I'm using Next.js with styled-jsx, testing enzyme + jest.

I want to test props style but I don't know How can I test.

**index.js**

```
const App = (props) => {
    const { className, styles } = styles(props);
    return (
        <div className={`${className}`}>
            <h1>test</h1>
            {styles}
        </div>
    )
}
```

**style.js**

```
import css from 'styled-jsx/css';
export default (props) => css.resolve`
    h1 {
        color: ${props.color} || "red";
    }
`
```

I tried to test this way but It's not working.

```
const wrapper = shallow(<App color={"blue"}/>);
expect(wrapper.find('h1').prop('style')).toHaveProperty('color', 'blue');
```

Is there way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using `react-test-renderer` npm package you can do snapshot testing for Style component. Try this, might help you:

```
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

test('Style component unit testing', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<App color={"blue"} />).toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
  expect(tree).toHaveStyleRule('color', 'red')
})
```

Comment: I’m using enzyme instead of react-test-renderer. And It also supports snapshot testing. I know the method toHaveStyleRule, but It’s from jest-styled-components npm package, not styled-jsx. Is it working well in styled-jsx too?

Comment: You can use `react-test-renderer` along with `Enzyme`. Also `toHaveStyleRule` will work perfectly with `react-test-renderer`.